# Create index with collation

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I want to create an index in alembic which will be similar to this:

```
CREATE INDEX my_index ON tab(columnA DESC, columnB COLLATE "da_DK" ASC, id DESC);
```

I know that I can do something like:

```
 op.create_index('my_index', 'tab', ['columnA', 'columnB'])
```

but I don't know how I can pass collate option.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. The solution was using:

```
op.create_index('my_index', 'tab', ['columnA', text('columnB COLLATE "da_DK" ASC')])
```